# exit event after touchup

Tags: java, libgdx

I have the following problem in `LibGDX`. When you move over an `Actor` you get the enter event from the `ClickListener` and the exit event when you move out of the bounding box of the `Actor`. I keep a boolean mouseOver that tells me if the cursor is over an `Actor` with these events. But when you click on the `Actor` and after releasing the mouse, an exit event is given. So after releasing the mouse click, it is as if the cursor isn't over the Actor anymore, while it is.

How can I keep a correct state for the boolean mouseOver? In other words: how can I know if the mouse is over my Actor when a TouchUp event has occurred as in the above scenario.

Answer (score 1):

You can override **touchUp** and set the boolean **mouseOver** to true there.

```
@Override
public void touchUp(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button){
    ...
    mouseOver = true;
}
```

Comment: That doesn't work because the exit event is called immediately after the touch up event. And I set mouseOver to false on the exit event.

Answer (score 0):

The best hack I found so far is to look at the pointer arg in the exit and enter overrides and look if the mouse is clicked. I'm still looking for a cleaner solution though.

```
    addListener(new ClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void enter(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer,
                Actor fromActor) {
            mouseOver = pointer == -1 ? true : mouseOver;
            super.enter(event, x, y, pointer, fromActor);
        }

        @Override
        public void exit(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer,
                Actor toActor) {
            mouseOver = pointer == -1 ? false : mouseOver;
            super.exit(event, x, y, pointer, toActor);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set **mouseOver** to false only if the Actor **toActor** of **exit** is not the actor you added the listener to:

```
myActor.addListener(new ClickListener() {
  ...
  @Override
  public void exit(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, Actor toActor) {
    ...
    if (toActor != myActor) // and even myActor's children if it is a Group
      mouseOver = false;
  }
});
```